# How to formulate constraints in linear programming so that a set of consecutive variables are forced to be equal?

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

Let's say we are optimizing over 2 variables, each a vector of 6. That is, Y=[y0,y1,...y5], and X=[x0, x1, ..., x5]. How do I formulate a constraint in linear programming so that it forces the following solutions: x0=x1=x2=x3 & x4=x5. Or is it better to penalize the differences (e.g. |x0-x1|) in the objective function? Is so, how?

Comment: Just do pairwise: `x0-x1=0`, `x1-x2=0`, `x2-x3=0`, `x4-x5=0`.

Answer (score 2):

x0=x1 can be expressed as x0-x1 <= 0 and x0-x1 >= 0. The other equalities in the same way.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, directly stating x0-x1 = 0 is the better way.

Comment: I would say `x0=x1` is better written as `x0-x1=0`. No need whatsoever to have two inequalities for each equality,

Comment: Yes,  I agree, that is better!